# Why do some players lose on purpose in Clash Royale?

Tags: clash-royale

I've noticed that some players lose games on purpose. That, or they are some kind of AI bots that are terrible.

They lose on purpose because they either don't spawn anything, or cast spells on useless positions. It's also clear they are 'real' players because once you beat them they often taunt 'thanks!'. So I wonder, what's the reason for this? Is it because you get better chests if you come back from a losing streak or something?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as primarily opinion based, since everyone will have their own ideas of why people throw matches. There's a broad number of reasons, none of which are a correct "one answer fits all".

Comment: Two more theories where I have done this: (1) I get a call in the middle of a game and forfeit to answer it; (2) I let a kid play with my phone and they open the match and play it badly or not at all; (3) Lose wifi connection in a match; (4) accidentally start a battle and don't realize it "Butt Battling"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People mainly do this because they want to lower in rank. Reason for this is that they have good cards. Then lower their rank so they fight people aren't as strong, so they can easily farm chests and gain more cards. Then repeating the process once more.

As mentioned by @thelord23 it also can be used during the launch of a clan chest to increase the chance of getting the rewards.

Answer (score 3):

When you have lower rank it is easier to get 3 crowns per battle, Usually people do this just before clan chests. They can contribute easily and quickly to the clan chest's total crowns.